# Where to submit bugs for Google's Chrome Reward Program?

Tags: google-chrome

I have found a bug on the Chrome OS system and would like to submit it to chrome to get a reward. Where would this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, did you try google it? Looks like there are a lot of info [here](https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/chrome-rewards/).

Comment: Thanks for your response but on that page, I could not find a link to the submission page on there.

Comment: Thank you I have found the page at: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/